# ¿Como Filtrar en un Array PHP?

Tags: php, array

Yo tengo un `Array` del cual necesito hacer un filtro, estoy utilizando [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php) de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

$arr = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4];

var_dump(array_filter($arr, function($v, $k) {
    return $k == 'b' || $v == 4;
  }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));
?>
```

Efectivamente funciona y me devuelve el resultado filtrado que es el indice `b` y el indice `d`, pero a mi lo que me gustaria es que me filtrara mas precisamente si el indice `b` es de Valor `2`.

Intente de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

    $arr = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4];

    var_dump(array_filter($arr, function($v, $k) {
        return $k == 'b' && $v == 4;
      }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));
    ?>
```

Pero no me retorna ningún valor.

Comment: Votando para cerrar como *error tipográfico*. Se resuelve modificando el 4 por un 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según tu código solo devolveras los arreglos cuyo indice sea 'b' y su valor sea 4, algo contradictorio a lo que tienes en el arreglo que filtras ya que el elemento que existe con el indice 'b' su valor es 2. Por tanto deberias cambiar tu condición en el return del array_filter

Antes tenias:

```
return $k == 'b' && $v == 4;
```

Ahora debería ser:

```
return $k == 'b' && $v == 2;
```

Comment: Gracias, si me di cuenta luego que era eso.

Comment: Bueno si acerte en mi respuesta marcala, que es importante para mi esos punticos jaja ;P

Comment: Quitame el negativo, es importante para mi xD jajajaj

Comment: Esto es un error tipografico, no deberia haber sido contestada si no cerrada por ese motivo.